# Graph vertex ordering degree problem: finding a k-ordering

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graph-theory, graph-traversal

Given a graph G, a k-ord

With an dering of 3 (k is the largest degree)

To be more cd so on.

**Find an algoriering if it exists**.

Comment: Your last edit appears to have accidentally deleted most of the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible approaches, depending on constraints like the complexity needed for the application.

One thing to note is that the greedy approach yields a valid ordering if one exists. If `V` is the full list of nodes and `d(v)` is the degree in the residual graph:

```
order = []
while |V| > 0:
    let v be the node with a minimum degree
    if d(v) > k return false
    add v to order
    remove v from the graph
return order
```

The main challenge is to maintain an order of the nodes that respects the degree updates. This can be solved by a heap, and in this case a Fibonacci heap is useful since it can update keys in `O(1)` amortized time.

Building the heap takes `O(n)`. Each node removal costs `O(log(n)) + O(k)`. Therefore, the overall complexity is `O(n·log(n) + n·k)`

Comment: Could you add an argument or a reference for the claim "the greedy approach yields a valid ordering if one exists"?

Comment: @Stef If false then there is some graph G with a valid ordering, where the greedy approach can't proceed because all remaining vertices have degree > k. Let's say in some other ordering these can be removed, and let v be the first to be removed in this other ordering. Then deg(v) must be <= k in this ordering, but its degree only wrt. vertices we haven't yet removed is > k, contradiction.

Comment: This is good, but I think it can be solved in O(n+e) time (e being # of edges)

Comment: As well, im not sure this is correct. doesn't this just return an ascending list sorted by degree?